# Last item in RecyclerView update position issue when using onSearch

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

When searching items, I use onQueryTextChange to update RecycleView adapter in order to show search results immediately. Sometimes the application fails when click on last item that stays in the adapter.  It fails with out of index exception and for some reason tries to call to any index other than zero (but there is only one item so it should be zero only). But sometimes it works.
Methods in the home fragment are:

```
private fun initSearchView() {
        fragmentHomeBinding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object :
            SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                return true
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                if (newText.isEmpty()) {
                    reloadAfterSearch()
                    return true
                }
                val result = homeFragmentViewModel.itemsForSearch.filter {
                    it.title.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(newText.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()))
                }
                reloadOnTextChange(result)
                return true
            }
        })
    }

    private fun reloadOnTextChange(result: List<Film>) {
        filmsAdapter.clearItems()
        filmsAdapter.addItems(result)
    }

    fun saveItems() {
        filmsAdapter.saveItemsForSearch(homeFragmentViewModel)
        fragmentHomeBinding.searchView.isIconified = false
    }

    fun reloadAfterSearch(): Boolean {
        filmsAdapter.clearItems()
        filmsAdapter.addItems(homeFragmentViewModel.itemsForSearch)
        return true
    }

    private fun initRecycler() {
        fragmentHomeBinding.mainRecycler.apply {
            adapter = filmsAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            addDecoration(this)
            pagesController = PagesController(homeFragmentViewModel, layoutManager)
            addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                    if (pagesController.isNeedToRequestNextPage(dy))
                        requestNextPage()
                }
            })
        }.also { filmsAdapter.setListener { launchDetailsFragment(it) }}
    }

    private fun addDecoration(recycler: RecyclerView) {
        val decorator = TopSpacingItemDecoration(DECORATOR_PADDING)
        recycler.addItemDecoration(decorator)
    }

    private fun launchDetailsFragment(film: Film) {
        (requireActivity() as MainActivity).launchDetailsFragment(film)
    }
```

Methods in Recycler Adapter:

```
 fun addItems(list: List<Film>) {
        val itemCountBeforeAdding = itemCount
        val itemsAdded = list.size
        items.addAll(list)
        notifyItemRangeInserted(itemCountBeforeAdding, itemsAdded)
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, itemsAdded)
    }

    fun clearItems() {
        val itemCountBeforeClear = itemCount
        items.clear()
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, itemCountBeforeClear)
    }
```

Great thanks in advance for any kind of participation

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that lambda of onclick catches the old position value
The solution is to change method onBindViewHolder in the adapter from:

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FilmViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[position])
        filmItemBinding.itemContainer.setOnClickListener { clickListener.onClick(items[position]) }
    }
```

to:

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FilmViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[holder.adapterPosition])
        filmItemBinding.itemContainer.setOnClickListener { clickListener.onClick(items[holder.adapterPosition]) }
    }
```